# Displaying most viewed posts from last 7 days with views count via Wordpress rss feed

Tags: php, wordpress, time, view, rss

I need two feeds for my WP-website. One should be ordinary wp post feed< the other - must show most viewed post from last seven days with views count. I also want to show post views from WP-PostViews plugin counter.

I tried it via adding WP-PostViews function to feed-rss2 . It works, but I cannot limit output to 7 seven days

```
get_most_viewed('post', 10);
```

Comment: Try this https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/49330/how-to-query-for-most-viewed-posts-and-show-top-5

Answer (score 0):

First thing we need to do is create a function that will detect post views count and store it as a custom field for each post. To do this, paste the following codes in your theme’s functions.php file.

```
function wpb_set_post_views($postID) {
    $count_key = 'wpb_post_views_count';
    $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
    if($count==''){
        $count = 0;
        delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
        add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
    }else{
        $count++;
        update_post_meta($postID, $count_key, $count);
    }
}
//To keep the count accurate, lets get rid of prefetching
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'adjacent_posts_rel_link_wp_head', 10, 0);
```

Now that you have this function in place, we need to call this function on the single post pages. This way the function knows exactly which post gets the credit for the views. To do this, you would need to paste the following code inside your single post loop:

```
wpb_set_post_views(get_the_ID());
```

you should simply add the tracker in your header by using wp_head hook. So paste the following code in your theme’s functions.php file. Once you have placed this, every time a user visits the post, the custom field will be updated.

```
function wpb_track_post_views ($post_id) {
    if ( !is_single() ) return;
    if ( empty ( $post_id) ) {
        global $post;
        $post_id = $post->ID;    
    }
    wpb_set_post_views($post_id);
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'wpb_track_post_views');
```

you want to display the post view count on your single post pages

```
function wpb_get_post_views($postID){
    $count_key = 'wpb_post_views_count';
    $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
    if($count==''){
        delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
        add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
        return "0 View";
    }
    return $count.' Views';
    }

Then inside your post loop add the following code:

wpb_get_post_views(get_the_ID());
```

If you want to sort the posts by view count, then you can do so easily by using the the wp_query post_meta parameter. The most basic example loop query would look like this:

```
<?php 
$popularpost = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => 4, 'meta_key' => 'wpb_post_views_count', 'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 'order' => 'DESC'  ) );
while ( $popularpost->have_posts() ) : $popularpost->the_post();

the_title();

endwhile;
?>
```

Reference website: https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-track-popular-posts-by-views-in-wordpress-without-a-plugin/

Comment: Thank you, Vasim. But I do not need views on single posts pages. I need views to be displayed in my rss post meta, limited to last seven days, how can I do it?